# CS50 recover Pset4 does not pass check50

Tags: c, image, jpeg, cs50, recover

This program is designed to recover images from a digital camera SD card. The program is not passing the last three checks when I run it through check50. The program does not recover 000.jpg, middle image, and image 049.jpg. The error message indicated the program timed out while waiting for program to exit. The debugging tool has not been able to help me with this. Thank you for your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// Buffer to store card data

// recover deleter images
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
// count is 2
    if(argc < 2)
{
        printf("usage: ./recover image.raw\n");
        return 1;
}
// Read file
char *file = argv[1];

FILE *card = fopen(file, "r");
unsigned char* buffer = malloc(512);

// Check that file is valid
if (fopen(file, "r") == NULL)
{
    printf("could not open %s.\n", file);
    return 1;
}


char* filename = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));

//JPGs created
 int img_count = 0;
 int test_counter = 0;
 FILE *img nodd= NULL;
 
 // Read 512 chars
 while (test_counter == 0)
{
    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 512, card);
// Detect JPEG
    if(buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && buffer[3] && 0xf0 == 0xe0)
    {

// Write JPEG
            sprintf(filename, "%0x3i.jpg", img_count);
            img = fopen(filename, "w");
            img_count++;

       while (true)
        {
            fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 512, card);

            if(buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && buffer[3] && 0xf0 == 0xe0)
            {
            sprintf(filename, "%0x3i.jpg", img_count);
            img = fopen(filename, "a");
            img_count++;
            test_counter++;
            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), 512, img);
            break;
            }
        else
            {
            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), 512, img);
            break;
        }
        }


        while (fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 512, card)!= 0)

        if(buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && buffer[3] && 0xf0 == 0xe0)
        {
// Pointer for JPG created
            fclose(img);
            sprintf(filename, "%0x3i.jpg", img_count);
            img = fopen(filename, "a");
            img_count++;
        }

            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), 512, img);
        }
}
free(buffer);
fclose(img);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you do `fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 512, card);`, how do you know exactly how many `char`s it actually read without checking the return value? Also, since `.jpg` is stored in a binary type of format, you should open the file with `"rb"`: `FILE *card = fopen(file, "rb");` it doesn't matter on Posix systems, but it does matter on Windows.

Comment: Try `printf("%0x3i.jpg", 2);` and see what you get. Is it what you expected?

Comment: Sidenote: Why do you open the file twice?

Comment: `char* filename = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));` could simply be `char filename[32];` Note that `3 * sizeof(int)` could be 6, 12, or 24 depending on the system that you run the code on.